# Using Datetime with format dd.MM.yyyy parses strings with only two digit year?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I need to validate Strings if they contain a valid Date-Input. For that I created a method

```
public static Date validateDateFormat(final String expectedDateFormat, final String dateToValdate) {


    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(expectedDateFormat);
    DateTime dt = null;

    try {
        dt = formatter.parseDateTime(dateToValdate);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("cannot parse {0} to format {1}", dateToValdate, expectedDateFormat);
    }
    if (dt != null) {
        return dt.toDate();
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }       
}
```

With these values it does not return null as expected. The string will be converted to a DateTime with the value 0018-12-18T00:00:00.000+00:53:28, is there a way to change this behaviour? I though that if the format is not correct, it will fail.

Here my Test

```
@Test
public void checkFormat6() {
    String date = "18.12.18";
    String expectedFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy";       

    assertNull(DateFormatChecker.validateDateFormat(expectedFormat, date));
}
```

I need to use JDK 7 and using joda-time 2.10

Comment: A range check? You know what range of dates you will accept, and since it doesn’t go back to year 18, reject any date that does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joda Time doesn't strictly match the `y`, `yy`, or `yyyy`. Even `d.M.y` pattern will parse `18.12.18` into a valid date time.

You can get a more strict pattern parsing with `java.time` classes (there is a backport for Java 7) e.g. by setting `ResolverStyle.STRICT`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(expectedFormat)
    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
```

Above will fail `dd.MM.yyyy` from your example but it will still let `d.M.y` parse `18.12.18`.